# Splitting a HTML document using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

We deal with long aggregated HTML documents (for conversion to PDF).
In some situations the aggregated HTML document must be split by chapter (dedicated HTML pages starting with a H1 tag) or by subchapters (dedicated HTML pages starting with each H1 or H2 tag). We are using BeautifulSoup for manipulating the aggregated HTML so far but we could not find a proper way using BeautifulSoup for extracting the subdocument (e.g. from first H1 to the next H2) in a proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some experience with working with BeautifulSoup and I'm not sure if it supports what you want to do directly. Here are two ideas

**Searching**

Following is some documentation of search facilities that it has. Maybe you can search for both H1s and H2s and see if that helps to extract subdocuments

[http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching the Parse Tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching%20the%20Parse%20Tree)

**Pretty Print + grep**

BeautifulSoup has a very useful prettify functionality to pretty print the html. Once that is done, each H1 or H2 will be on its own line, in which case, one can easily use text manipulation utilities like grep to easily determine line no. containing H1 and H2 and simple take the text in-between.

[http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Printing a Document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Printing%20a%20Document)

Comment: Well, I am pretty aware of the BeautifulSoup functionality and don#t need pointers to the documentation I know in and out :)

Comment: Glad to know that you know the documentation in and out. I did present 2 points, the 2nd of which being more than just a pointer to the documentation. I just felt a different approach might be needed. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Since no solution with a parser has been proposed to you, may I suggest that you should manage by yourself with regular expressions ?

The second point of Danish is of the same nature, as the name grep comes from 'global - regular expression - print'. But it is complicated by the fact the prettify functionality must be used for a preliminary treatment.

On the contrary, regular expressions are a powerful tool, that can be used directly on a text.

Could you give more information on what you want to do ?